# Fullpage.js buggy slide animation after chrome version update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullpage.js

js in my page it was working fine before, but with the recent chrome update showing me following errors in console while scrolling using mouse wheel,

"Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312"

Because of this the sliding is very buggy and glitchy, can someone please help me on this.

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/cary1234/nppyyqax/4/ if you remove the `scrollBar: true,` option it will work fine, but I need this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they have fixed the issue in new build, you can update to fix the bug.
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3600